# Regular expression for extracting Classic ASP include file names

Tags: regex, vb.net, asp-classic

I am searching for a **Regular Expression** that can help me extract `filename.asp` from the below string. It seems like a simple task, but I am unable to find a solution.

This is my input:

```
<!-- #include file="filename.asp" -->
```

I want output of regular expression like this:

```
filename.asp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and find the following solution.

Regular Expression:

```
/#include\W+file="([^"]+)"/g
```

Example code (VB.NET):

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)
Dim regex = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("#include\W+file=""([^""]+)""")
Dim matchResult = regex.Match(filetext)
While matchResult.Success
    list.Add(matchResult.Groups(1).Value)
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch()
End While
```

Example code (C#):

```
var list = new List<string>();
var regex = new Regex("#include\\W+file=\"([^\"]+)\"");
var matchResult = regex.Match(fileContent);
while (matchResult.Success) {
    list.Add(matchResult.Groups[1].Value);
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```

Improved Regular Expression (ignores spaces):

```
#include\W+file[\s]*=[\s]*"([^"]+)"
```

Comment: If you could research in couple of seconds, why did u post the question?!

Comment: There is no final answer yet. The above code will not work with spaces after 'file ='.

Comment: It should work(the regex) even if there are spaces after `file=`

Comment: try this: `#include\W+file[\s]*=[\s]*"([^"]+)"` :)

Comment: @PruthviRaj `<!-- #INCLUDE File = "bana" & "na.asp" -->`. I see your expression and raise you an absurd exception to it. Don't use regexp, use substrings and character walking, because you can verify as you go.